# Trying to avoid duplicated records from a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have 2 tables with the following structure:

```
 ------------------------------------
| dbo.Katigories  | dbo.Products     |
|-----------------|------------------|
| product_id      | product_id       |
| Cat_Main_ID     | other data.....  |
| Cat_Sub_ID      | other data.....  |
| Cat_Sub_Sub_ID  | other data.....  |
| other data..... | other data.....  |
```

I want to retrieve all the products from the `dbo.Products` table, having the same `Cat_Main_ID` and the same `Cat_Sub_ID`. To do that, I have the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.katigories, dbo.Products
WHERE
dbo.katigories.Cat_Main_ID  = (the Cat_Main_ID – exists_in-my url - query string)
AND
dbo.katigories.Cat_Sub_ID  = (the Cat_Sub_ID – exists_in-my url - query string)
AND
dbo.katigories.product_id = dbo.Products.product_id
```

Unfortunately, this SELECT statement giving me duplicated records of products.
I know why this is happening: The reason is that some of the products belong simultaneously to many categories or subcategories. What I do not know is the way I can manage to get only unique records from the `Products` table. Only the unique `product_id` without duplicated.

Can someone please help with the correct syntax of my query?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  I surmise SQL Server from the syntax.

Comment: use distinct keyword in your query.

Comment: Use JOIN...ON syntax, we are not in 1982.

Comment: @Tobb I know.. but unfortunately I am completely inexperience with this

Comment: @Freddakos all the more reason to learn the proper modern syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use this trick:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES *
FROM dbo.katigories k JOIN
     dbo.Products p
     ON k.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE k.Cat_Main_ID  = (the Cat_Main_ID – exists_in-my url - query string) AND
      k.Cat_Sub_ID  = (the Cat_Sub_ID – exists_in-my url - query string)
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.product_id ORDER BY NEWID());
```

In other databases, you would do the some thing very similar with `ROW_NUMBER()` in a subquery or CTE.

Notes:

- `SELECT *` is dangerous, because you have columns with the same names.
- *Always* use correct, proper, standard, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- Table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.

Comment: I think it works properly. Thank you very much and I ask for your understanding for the oldfashioned syntax I am using..

Comment: I apologize for bothering you again about the same issue. First of all I want to let you know, that your code works perfectly!!! What I now want to ask you, is a way I can use the COUNT command so that I can count the result I am getting from the query you gave me. Can I add the word COUNT somewhere in your code (for example after the SELECT) ) (or somewhere else)? And if so, where exactly??

Comment: @Freddakos . . . I don't know exactly what you mean by `count(*)`.  I think you can add `count(*) over ()` to get the total number of rows returned by the query without the `top`.  Perhaps you should ask another question.

Comment: Thanks! I will do that!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add the directive 'DISTINCT' after the directive 'SELECT'